# Toner cartridges in or out when the machine is turned off for 6 months

Tags: laser-printer

I have a Brother Laser MFC-9130 printer. It will be turned off and unused for six months. In order to maintain operability of the printer and the toner cartridges for this extended period of non-operation, should I leave the cartridges in or take them out? (If it’s best to take them out, is there any particular way I should store them?)

Comment: The nice thing about laser printers is that you can turn them off for 5 years and plug them in and they’ll print like the day you turned it off. You couldn’t turn an inkjet off for a week and be able to print still. Leave everything in the printer and store it in a cool & dry place out of direct sunlight. Covering it to protect from dust would be even better. Don’t take it to an outdoor storage unit and expect it to work right when you go back to it.

Comment: It wouldn't make a difference. Toner is dry powder. It can't dry up because it's already dry. I'd just leave it in the printer.

Answer (score 0):

Moisture is the enemy. Removing the printer cartridge leave more space for moisture to get in

Better to leave.

Much better to place again the printer in the box with a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silica_gel

Answer (score -2):

I would leave in.
Why would be better if you take it out?
Of course it is suggested to store in a cool & dry place.
Warm should not hurt the printer itself, but ink could agglomerate in elevated temperatures and/or high humidity.
If you store outside of the printer, do not expose to sun, toners are usually black in color and prolonged sunlight could deformate them.

Comment: Always did with my former laser (b&w) so it would recognize the time left on the toner.

Comment: Hmm. Toners (or printers) are counting pages, not toner age IMO.